# Flink Job not printing anything to StdOut

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, watermark

I have a Flink Job that I can't understand why it won't print to standard output. I notice that If I remove my filter and watermark, I see raw messages from my kafka topic. But applying an aggregation and a watermark, I don't get anything. Here's my code under main()

```
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // // create kafka source

    KafkaSource<VideoAdCompletedEvent> videoAdsSource = KafkaSource
    .builder()
    .setBootstrapServers(jobConfig.kafkaSourceServer)
    .setTopics(jobConfig.sourceKafkaTopic).setGroupId(jobConfig.consumerGroupId)
    .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new VideoDeserSchema())
    .build();

    WatermarkStrategy<VideoAdCompletedEvent> watermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy
    .<VideoAdCompletedEvent>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(30)) // allow events up to 30 seconds out of order
    .withTimestampAssigner(
        (event, timestamp) -> event.getOriginTs()
    )
    .withIdleness(Duration.ofMillis(500));

    DataStream<VideoAdCompletedEvent> videoAdsStream = env
    .fromSource(videoAdsSource, watermarkStrategy, "Mobile Analytics Filtered Video Ads Topic")
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy);

    DataStream<VideoAdCompletedEvent> filteredStream = videoAdsStream
    .filter(new FilterFunction<VideoAdCompletedEvent>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(VideoAdCompletedEvent message) throws Exception {
          return (message.getCompletedReason().equals("VIDEO_FINISHED") || message.getCompletedReason().equals("video_finished"));
        }
    });

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>>  aggStream = filteredStream
        .keyBy((VideoAdCompletedEvent event) -> event.getVideoId())
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30)))
        .aggregate(new DistinctUserIdAggregate(), new VideoIdCountProcessFunction());

    SinkFunction<VideoAdCompletedEvent> printSink = new PrintSinkFunction();

    aggStream.addSink(printSink);

    env.execute("Test Job");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could there be any empty Kafka partitions? That would explain it.

Comment: Hi David - he's got a withIdleness() on his watermark strategy...wouldn't that handle the idle partition situation?

Comment: Hi Ken - you're right. Somehow I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

A few possible explanations...

1. Your `FilterFunction` is removing all events.
2. Your `VideoIdCountProcessFunction` isn't generating any results.
3. All events have watermarks within the same 60 second time interval, thus you never generate a watermark that causes a window to fire.

Adding additional logging and/or counters would help figure out where events are being removed.

Note that the call to `.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()` should be removed, as you're already passing the watermark strategy to the Kafka source via the `.fromSource()` call.